# Regex search in visual studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to find all string literals in Visual Studio which are not empty and not commented out, so I'm using the regular expression search

```
^((?!//).)*".+"
```

Which I'm hoping will match the line

```
 get { return System.Environment.UserName.ToUpper() == "MYUSERNAME"; }
```

but not

```
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ApplicationContext"/> class.
```

This seems to match what I want on the regex tester at http://regexpal.com but in Visual studio it gives no results.

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Try `^((?!//).)@".@"`. No idea if the VS2010 find and replace supports lookarounds in Find and replace, but I hope yest.

Comment: It appears it doesn't... I tried the same regex in WinGrep but got the error, "Invalid use of a repeat"...

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of Visual Studio (before 2012) used their own dialect of regular expressions that are very different to .NET's dialect.

Help for VS's dialect is on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

*Edit*: It was VS2012 that switched to using .NET regular expressions.